# mod_rewrite to redirect raw percent sign in URL instead of Bad Request 400

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a bunch of URLs like the following:

```
http://domain.com/is-20%-into-401k-enough/
```

I am aware that, by standards, they are malformed URIs therefore going to this URL directly will result in a Bad Request from the server.

Here are a few questions:

1. I thought browsers automatically encode this so that the server sees %25 instead of just %? Why doesn't it work in this case?
2. Can I use mod_rewrite to redirect this malformed URI into an correct one (`/is-20%25-into-401k-enough/`)?

Here is where I'm at but I think the bad request is getting priority because the RewriteCond seems to be looking for %25 in the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \%
RewriteRule . $0 [B]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your browser encode % character in %25. I'm not sur to understand, you would like rewrite % character ? in which url character ?

Comment: I would like to rewrite % to redirect it to %25 because the browser doesn't seem to be doing it. I tried all browsers. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/20%